# Angular 4 image marker

Tags: image, angular, pointers, marker

I'm currently working in an Angular 4 app which has to display an image in which anyone could mark a point and add a text, I've seen a lot of Jquery Plugins that do the work, but I don't like the idea of combining Jquery and Angular, anyone knows about an angular component that works for generic pictures?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A quick google search, brought up this tool, which seems to have the functionality you want, though may be a bit overkill. I haven't used it myself, so I have no idea how well it works: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-photo-editor

Alternatively, using the canvas API isn't too difficult for something as simple as overlaying text and marking some points. This tutorial seems to go through some of the basics: https://objectpartners.com/2016/09/22/using-the-canvas-api-in-angular2/

Comment: thank you so much I'll check on that tutorial, I'm new to angular and this JS technologies so it's kind of overwhelming, thanks again.

Comment: If you never used the editor, why are you proposing a solution? You get only a binary license for ng2-photo-editor, and I did not find even a prize for this sdk.